# Mock JsonNode using Mockito in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

How can I mock these two loc using mockito in spring boot.

```
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(httpResponseObject.getResponseBody(), JsonNode.class);
    String token = jsonNode.get("token").asText();
```

I have mocked the first loc using below mocking but don't know how to mock the second loc.

```
String jsonString = TestingUtil.getResponse();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);


    Mockito.when(objectMapper.readValue(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(jsonNode);
```

but here jsonNode is returning null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is detail explanation of mocking `objectMapper`.

https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-jackson-read-value

Actually in terms of unit testing, there is no difference between objectMapper and any class to test. Simply add dependency to be mocked, specify rule for it(e.g when->then), assert it.

--EDIT--

Add JsonNode as mock object.

```
JsonNode mockNode = mock(JsonNode.class);
JsonNode innerMockNode = mock(JsonNode.class);
Mockito.when(objectMapper.readValue(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(mockNode);
Mockito.when(mockNode.get("token")).thenReturn(innerMockNode);
Mockito.when(innerMockNode.asText()).thenReturn("myToken");
```

Comment: I have gone through this already, but second Line of code which takes token out of JsonNode. I am not able to mock that

Comment: I just added more detail to answer.

Comment: Alper, I am still getting NPE. JsonNode.get("token").asText() is giving this

Comment: I think you need another inner JsonNode.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, do you mean mocking another JsonNode ?

Comment: I just edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243483/discussion-between-alper-derya-and-aditya).